# DSE Services automatically shutting down

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Hello Cassandra Experts,

We're observing an unusual situation where the Cassandra services are shutting down on their own, we have setup a 3-node Cassandra cluster. We have automated the Cassandra startup using a script that would start the Cassandra services for 1st node, then sleep for 60 seconds, and then begin the Cassandra services for 2nd node followed by the 3rd node.
However, we observe all the nodes are showing **UN** status for 2-3 minutes but after some time as per the Cassandra logs a DSE shutdown is initiated and all services are gracefully shut down. Could please review the attached cassandra logs, config. files and recommend if you find anything unusual in our configuration or any best practice on how to automate the cassandra services startup behavior.

Cassandra logs uploaded: https://filetransfer.io/data-package/wRNkcTEk#link

```
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2022-10-31 23:22:43,742  MessageServer.java:130 - internode-messaging message server finished shutting down.
INFO  [NodeSync-1] 2022-10-31 23:22:43,747  NodeSyncService.java:552 - Disabled NodeSync service
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2022-10-31 23:22:43,748  HintsService.java:224 - Paused hints dispatch
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2022-10-31 23:22:43,748  Gossiper.java:1975 - Announcing shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2022-10-31 23:22:45,728  MessagingService.java:695 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2022-10-31 23:22:45,739  MessagingService.java:695 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2022-10-31 23:22:45,750  MessagingService.java:695 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2022-10-31 23:22:50,275  HintsService.java:224 - Paused hints dispatch
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2022-10-31 23:22:50,277  HintsService.java:224 - Paused hints dispatch
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2022-10-31 23:22:50,282  HintsService.java:224 - Paused hints dispatch
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2022-10-31 23:22:50,361  StorageService.java:6441 - Using default non periodic tasks shutdown timeout 1 minutes
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2022-10-31 23:22:50,366  PluginManager.java:195 - Plugins are stopped.
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2022-10-31 23:22:50,366  DseDaemon.java:965 - DSE shutdown complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

A friendly note to let you know that asking for someone to review logs isn't something you would normally ask in a public forum. You need to review the logs yourself for clues because this isn't a paid support service.

What I did notice is that the log files you posted shows multiple entries for the same thing which leads me to believe that all your nodes are sharing the same filesystem which is not allowed.

For example, there are multiple entries for "No host ID found":

```
WARN  [DSE main thread] 2022-11-01 00:38:05,596  StorageService.java:1212 - No host ID found, created ab3baad3-33a3-42f7-ab90-afb0976fcdd2 (Note: This should happen exactly once per node).
WARN  [DSE main thread] 2022-11-01 00:40:12,174  StorageService.java:1212 - No host ID found, created 136a81e3-0213-4575-a622-34b65545d882 (Note: This should happen exactly once per node).
WARN  [DSE main thread] 2022-11-01 00:42:18,139  StorageService.java:1212 - No host ID found, created 2ce602d5-4285-4299-8522-99b32b685f49 (Note: This should happen exactly once per node).
```

As the warning message states:

```
... (Note: This should happen exactly once per node).
```

so it makes no sense that there are multiple entries like that.

The `StartupChecks` also reports that the nodes are using NFS:

```
WARN  [DSE main thread] 2022-11-01 00:42:18,029  StartupChecks.java:1135 - saved caches directory /mnt/provision/dlpxstgcluster/dse-6.8.25_delphix_n_2/saved_caches on device 10.43.89.253:/domain0/group-115/appdata_container-118/appdata_timeflow-119/datafile (appears to be rotational with logical sector size 512) uses a not recommended file system type 'nfs', (mounted as /mnt/provision/dlpxstgcluster)
WARN  [DSE main thread] 2022-11-01 00:42:18,029  StartupChecks.java:1135 - commitlog directory /mnt/provision/dlpxstgcluster/dse-6.8.25_delphix_n_2/commitlog on device 10.43.89.253:/domain0/group-115/appdata_container-118/appdata_timeflow-119/datafile (appears to be rotational with logical sector size 512) uses a not recommended file system type 'nfs', (mounted as /mnt/provision/dlpxstgcluster)
WARN  [DSE main thread] 2022-11-01 00:42:18,029  StartupChecks.java:1135 - data directory /mnt/provision/dlpxstgcluster/dse-6.8.25_delphix_n_2/data on device 10.43.89.253:/domain0/group-115/appdata_container-118/appdata_timeflow-119/datafile (appears to be rotational with logical sector size 512) uses a not recommended file system type 'nfs', (mounted as /mnt/provision/dlpxstgcluster)
```

You need to sort out the configuration of your cluster and try again. Make sure that you are not using shared storage. Cheers!